# Unable to instantiate SparkContext from pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm able to import SparkContext. However, once I try to instantiate it, the following error appears:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have Java installed and your `JAVA_HOME` set.